Arduino and custom pcb
I am looking to minimize the size and assembly complexity of my arduino projects. Is there any easy way to integrate something like an esp8266 onto my own pcb. I don't want to have to solder it on. In the end I would like to have a custom pcb with all my electronics and instead of then having to solder my esp 8266 onto that board, it would already be integrated. I am quite a noob. I know that you can integrate the esp8266 chip onto a pcb, but is there a way to integrate like the chip and all of the other stuff that's usually on an esp8266 module in one step. Like the port for uploading and the voltage regulator etc. Thanks for all the advice in advance

A custom PCB is - well - custom. The whole principle is, that you are doing it yourself. If you don't want to solder it yourself, you can use an assembly service of a PCB manufacturer. They will place and solder the components for you, so that you get a ready to use PCB.

It is unclear to me what you are asking. You want or don't want to use a ready made esp8266 board as part of your project? If you get a Wemos D1 mini you can put it ioto female headers integrated into your PCB.

Is this what you want?

I don't want to solder a D1 mini or something similar onto my printed pcb. What I am looking for is to integrate the esp8266 IC onto my own pcb. (so instead of soldering esp module pcb onto my pcb, they are both on the same pcb) I would have a company smd solder it onto the pcb.

It is unclear, what your actual problem is. Sure, you can put the ESP8266 directly on your PCB. The same with voltage regulator and USB port. What is the actual problem in creating this PCB?

Well I have no idea what all I need. I have never done something like this before and I thought this community was for people that need guidance

Almost every chip or module come with datasheet or hardware design guide, you need to read those to understand what you need prior to the design of your custom board. For ESP8266, read the ESP8266 Hardware Design Guidelines. If you are new to hardware design, consider to use readily-made module such as ESP-12S.

Instead of soldering the module directly onto the board, you could design a slot or socket for an ESP8266 module like the ESP-12. This would allow you to easily place and replace the module without direct soldering.

You can buy ESP8266 modules pre-assembled with pin headers. Like this
one for example (not a specific recommendation, just the first
organic Google result). You can then solder this module on your PCB just
like you would solder any DIP package. Alternatively, you can solder a
DIP socket on your PCB, and then plug the module on the socket.
